# Showing a map with a marker using codeingiter and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am storing in my database lat and lng and trying to show a map in my view. but nothing is showing my code

```
<script>
var lat = <?php $property['LATITUDE']); ?>;
var long = <?php $property['LONGITUDE']); ?>;
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 16
    });
    var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById('pano'), {
            position: myCenter,
            pov: {
                heading: 34,
                pitch: 10
            }
        });
    map.setStreetView(panorama);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map" style="float:left; height:400px; width:49.5%;"></div>
<div id="pano" style="float:right; height:400px; width:49.5%;">></div>
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

my model

```
function get_single_property($id)
{
    $q = $this->db->select('*')->from('properties')->where('id', $id)->get();
    $results = $q->result_array();
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Any JavaScript errors?  What is the generated output when you view your HTML source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem i can see, if you lat,lng are correct of course in the database is that you are missing this:

```
var lat = <?php echo json_encode($property['LATITUDE']); ?>;
var long = <?php echo json_encode($property['LONGITUDE']); ?>;
```

As you may know you need to print your data if you are passing it, and Javascript needs to accept data from php as JSON object. which is why we added json_encode.